# Unable to connect to Server: WIN-71KGFN2PPCC\SQLEXPRESS in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php on line 7 Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, iis-7.5, vps

I have tested my MS SQL Server connection with this PHP code:

```
<?php
// Server in the this format: <computer>\<instance name> or 
// <server>,<port> when using a non default port number
$server = 'WIN-71KGFN2PPCC\SQLEXPRESS';

// Connect to MSSQL
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'sa', 'test1234');

if (!$link) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}else{

}
?>
```

and had this warning and error message:

```
Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: WIN-71KGFN2PPCC\SQLEXPRESS in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php on line 7
Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL
```

I tried many solutions, I also enabled the TCP/IP protocol of my MS SQL Server from the SQL Configuration Manager, adding the port 1433 to it and to the firewall. Any other solution to it? Please help me.

Comment: I suggest you could firstly make sure the WIN-71KGFN2PPCC is the right address which could access your MS sql server. I suggest you could try to use IP address of your sql server and try again.

Comment: I tried it already, i get the same error.

Comment: I suggest you could try to download a SSMS and directly connect to your sqlexpress to make sure the address , hostname , username, password is right.

Comment: I have sql server management studio 2012 and its correctly configured. i can login to it using the credentials above.

Comment: I suggest you could try to check your Microsoft SQL Server Driver for PHP version. I suggest you could download it from this [url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php) and try to update the driver version to the newest version.